# Tiles from lower resolutions still visible in the map

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers to display information on a tile grid with multiple resolution levels, with different tile sizes on each level. However, when zooming IN, the lower level (larger) tiles are still visible, but when zooming OUT, the higher level tiles (smaller) disappear. Is there anyway to only show the tiles for the particular resolution interval you're in?

Comment: Could you point us to a working example of your code?